# Does Alpine drop packages from old base images?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am currently using alpine:3.13 as my base image. There, I had installed nodejs using: `apk add nodejs=~14.15`. However, the 3.13 branch contains a new nodejs (14.16) and 14.15 does not exist anymore. Because of this, my image build fails.

This is really annoying and fails to serve Docker's purpose. What are the possible solutions to not have to keep updating the package numbers? I think I read it somewhere, but I don't remember where that 'packages from older Alpine images are not dropped. For example, in alpine:3.12, we have nodejs=12.21.0-r0 and this specific version will not be dropped from alpine:3.12'. Is the previous statement true? If not, what can be done to maintain consistency?

Answer (score 0):

Alpine indeed drops old package versions, which are superseded by new package versions. While this ensures only latest and updated packages are available, it could indeed cause image maintenance headache, especially if an image depends on specific package versions.

If you're not bound to a specific package version, then don't use version pinning. That is, install the package by it's name only:

```
apk add nodejs
```

Then, when the package is upgraded with `apk upgrade`, it will be updated to the latest version available in Alpine repositories.

> packages from older Alpine images are not dropped. For example, in alpine:3.12, we have nodejs=12.21.0-r0 and this specific version will not be dropped from alpine:3.12

This isn't really true. Alpine rolls out updates to packages regularly. In many cases, you could still find old package versions in repositories of older Alpine versions. But, if there's a critical security fix to some package, for example, it's likely that it will be applied in all Alpine repositories that are not end-of-life. Then, there won't be a way to obtain it, since all Alpine mirrors repositories are updated almost simultaneously (in this case, for obtaining the specific package version, you'll have to get it from a pre-built image that already contains it).